# My django application is deployed on heroku, can i use nginx to serve just the media and static files?

Tags: django, nginx

I deployed my django application on heroku. And, I want to know if i can serve the static and media files using nginx. I know i can use amazon s3 instead, but for now i dont have access to it yet cause i dont have a debit or credit card to complete my account.

Comment: You don't use nginx on Heroku.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use first, use `python manage.py collectstatic`

and then your nginx confg like this

```
server {
     ...
    location /static/ {
    }

    location /media/ {
    }
    ...
}
```